# Sass mixins are not replacing variables

Tags: sass

I'm trying to use a SASS mixin to automatically use vendor-prefixes on animations. This is the mixin:

```
@mixin keyframes($name) {
    @-o-keyframes $name { @content };
    @-moz-keyframes $name { @content };
    @-webkit-keyframes $name { @content }; 
    @keyframes $name { @content };
}
```

Now if I include it like this:

```
@include keyframes(test) {
    from {
        opacity: 0; 
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The resulting css looks like this:

```
@-o-keyframes $name { ... }
@-moz-keyframes $name { ... }
@-webkit-keyframes $name { ... }
@keyframes $name { ... }
```

SASS is simply not replacing the `$name` with `test`. Is this a known bug or are there workarounds? I couldn't find anything related to this problem. I'm using SASS version 3.4.1 by the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `$name` to `#{$name}` in the mixin

```
@mixin keyframes($name) {
  @-o-keyframes #{$name} { @content };
  @-moz-keyframes #{$name} { @content };
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} { @content }; 
  @keyframes #{$name} { @content };
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oIFsK)

Comment: This works, but it is a bug right? The documentation does not mention this.

Comment: It actually [is part of the spec](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)

Comment: Yep but according to the doc, it should be working without having to do the interpolation: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-arguments (this issue suddently appeared on my project too.. Your answer solved the problem, but I'd like to know why this happens)